# Find all natural numbers $n$ that divide $1^n + 2^n + \cdots+ (n-1)^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem: Find all natural numbers $n$ that divide $1^n + 2^n + \cdots + (n-1)^n$

Actually, this isn't homework, but I'll add a homework tag just in case. The problem is from Santos' Number theory for mathematical contests. I don't know where to start from to solve this problem. Absolutely nothing comes to my mind at the moment.

Comment: What you want to do is find all $n$ such that $$1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n\equiv 0\mod n$$ is true or all $m$ such that  $$1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n\equiv 0\mod m$$?

Comment: see: [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: I also have problem with that ambiguity, but this is exactly how the problem has been phrased verbatim. I personally assumed that he means the second one, the first one is a bit easier.

Comment: it only makes sense to me to be the first one

Comment: @oldrinb: If it's the first one, then half of the problem is obvious. If n is odd, then $1^{2k+1} + \cdots + 2k^{2k+1}$ is obviously divisible by n because $(n-1) \equiv -1$, $(n-2) \equiv -2$ .... (mod n). And since the number of terms are even, then they get canceled in pairs and it's done. The case where n is even could be a little bit trickier, but shouldn't be hard I guess.

Answer (score 2):

As Peter Tamaroff pointed out, the question is ambiguous. The problem could be interpreted as $1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n\equiv 0\mod n$ or $1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n\equiv 0\mod m$. If the first interpretation is correct then the answer is as follows:

$n$ is either odd or even, if it's odd, then the problem is actually quite easy:

**1)** $n=2k+1$ for some k:

$1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n\equiv 0\mod n \iff 1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n\equiv 1^n + 2^n + \cdots (-2)^n + (-1)^n \mod n$ because $n-1 \equiv -1 \mod n$, $n-2 \equiv -2 \mod n$ and so forth.. Also, since $n=2k+1$, the number of terms of $1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n$ will be even and all the terms will get canceled in pairs. Therefore, we'll always have $1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n\equiv 0 \mod n$ in this case and all odd numbers are accepted.

**2)** $n=2k$ for some k:

We claim that there is no solution in this case, but we have to consider two different cases where $k=2l$ or $k=2l+1$.

*a)* If $k=2l+1$ is indeed odd, then the proof is easy and straightforward as follows:

Let $1^{2k}+2^{2k}+\cdots+(2k-1)^{2k}\equiv 0\mod 2k$. That means $2k \mid 1^{2k}+2^{2k}+\cdots+(2k-1)^{2k}$, but that implies $2 \mid 1^{2k}+2^{2k}+\cdots+(2k-1)^{2k}$, i.e. :

$1^{2k}+2^{2k}+\cdots+(2k-1)^{2k} \equiv 0 \mod 2$, but since the number of terms in this case are odd, we can always find a middle term and isolate it. The other terms will get doubled because $ 1^{2k} \equiv (2k-1)^{2k} \mod (2k) $ and so forth.. Therefore, only the middle term will remain because the rest of the terms are divisible by 2.. and the middle term will be $k=2l+1$ which is odd, and we know that an odd number raised to any power remains odd. therefore $ 1 \equiv 0 \mod 2$ and that's contradiction. Therefore, there are no solutions when $n$ is even and $k$ is odd.

*b)* Now suppose $n=2k$ and $k$ is even. We can rewrite $n$ as $n=2^mt$ where $2 \nmid t$ by factoring out powers of 2 out of $k$. First of all, observe that:

$\Large \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: n < 2^n$

We can use this fact to see that:

$\Large 2^m \mid 2^{2^m} \mid 2^{2^mt} \mid (2s)^{2^mt} \mid (2s)^{n}$ where $2s$ is an even term of $1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n$. That forces all even terms of $1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n$ to vanish to zero $\mod 2^m$. Therefore, only the odd terms of $1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n$ will remain non-zero $\mod 2^m$. But $\varphi(2^m) = 2^m - 2^{m-1} = 2^{m-1}$ and since $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$ we'll have:

$\Large 1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n \equiv (1)^{2^mt} + (3)^{2^mt} + \cdots + (2^mt-1)^{2^mt} \equiv (1^{2^{m-1}})^{2t} + (3^{2^{m-1}})^{2t} + \cdots + ((2^mt-1)^{2^{m-1}})^{2t} \equiv (1)^{2t}+(1)^{2t}+\cdots+(1)^{2t} \equiv (2^{m-1}t)\cdot(1) \not\equiv 0 \mod 2^m $
Because $ 2 \nmid t$ and $2^{m-1} \nmid 2^m$ and there are $2^{m-1}t$ terms that all become $1$.

That proves $2^m \nmid 1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n$ when $n=2^mt$. Therefore this case is also settled.

This means that our statement is true only when $n$ is an odd number. I hope that my proof is now correct and complete.

Now, is it possible to solve the other interpretation?

Comment: The argument is not right. If $n$ is of the form $4k+2$, then indeed the sum is odd, but not when $n$ is of the form $4k$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I'm having trouble understanding your point. I'm saying that the number of terms in the sum is odd if n is even, this is because there are n-1 terms, not that the sum is odd. Is that wrong? or you mean something else is wrong? Also, why do I need to consider the case when n=4k+2 if I have already considered all cases?

Comment: The number of terms in the sum is certainly odd. However, that does not lead to a contradiction. The middle term need not be odd. Consider, for example, $n=4$. The middle term is $2$. Or let $n=8$. The middle term is $4$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Ah, yes. You're right. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll try to fix that soon.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Would you please do me a favor and re-read the proof again? I hope I have corrected my mistake and considered all possible cases this time. Please let me know if there is any other issues with my proof.

Comment: I will have to go through the details, but the argument looks correct. We are always short one power of $2$. Am confident enough that there are no slips to upvote.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks for your help André. Now, this is only one interpretation of the question, which is the easier one. The other interpretation looks more exotic, but unfortunately I think it's not possible to give a general solution to that one. Do you, or anyone else on here, have any ideas about how to approach that one? I tried to examine it for some n's, but I see no easy pattern for a general solution. : (

Comment: The natural interpretation of the question is "Find all $n$ **such that** $\dots$. Describing for fixed but indefinite $n$ all divisors is probably hopeless. It seems likely, and probably not hard to prove, that any $m$ is a divisor for some $n$.